# How to reduce size of all PPT/PPTX files in folder?

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-powerpoint

I have 1000+ PPT/PPTX files, how to reduce size of them all? It's OK if resolution of images goes down or history is gone. As long as current on slides text is preserved and images are recognizable, everthing is fine.

Comment: There is an option in PowerPoint that allows you to [compress](https://nutsandboltsspeedtraining.com/powerpoint-tutorials/powerpoint-compress-images/) images

Comment: However, if your intent is to compress all files at once, you can use this [option](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4028088/windows-zip-and-unzip-files) in the context menu

Comment: Zipping may help with PPT files, but not with PPTX files, which are already ZIP files internally. There are commercial products that do a good job of shrinking presentation files; one I know of is the desktop product from Neuxpower:  https://www.neuxpower.com/nxpowerlite-desktop/

Comment: @SteveRindsberg yes NxPowerLite is great and works wonders.

Comment: @ClassCastException glad to hear it. I probably should have mentioned that I have acquaintances who work there.  And that if I'd provided a special link that you used to purchase it, I'd have maybe gotten a small percentage; which is why I didn't do that.  ;-)

Comment: Why not save as pdf or jpeg? || with pdf.. you still got the text, with jpeg.. at least we know how to re-build/edit the pictured-slides.  IMHO..its a fair trade off... ( :